# Function: variable substitute

Tags: c, function

I'am having some trouble with the code below; I know it's rudimentary stuff for you more experienced coders, but this is my first time trying to code something in C so please bear with me.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("This program, or function, substitutes one given number for another given number, and then places the former with the latter number. ");

    float y1 = 10;  /* Assign value to variable 1*/
    float y2 = 20;  /* Assign value to variable 2*/
    float y3 = 30;  /* Assign value to variable 3*/
    float y4 = 40;  /* Assign value to variable 4*/

    void sub( float *, float *, float *, float * );                 /*declare function prototype*/

    printf("\nThe numbers' given values before the aforementioned function:  Number 1 = %f , Number 2 = %f\n , Number 3 = &f , Number 4 = %f", y1, y2, y3, y4 );
    sub( &y1, &y2, &y3, &y4 );   /*This is where the function, to move the numbers, is called */
    printf("\nThe numbers' given values after the aforementioned function:   Number 1 = %f , Number 2 = %f\n , Number 3 = &f , Number 4 = %f", y1, y2, y3, y4 );
}

void sub(float *z1, float *z2, float *n3, float *n4)
{
    int z;
    int n;
    z = *z1;
    *z1 = *z2;
    *z2 = z;
    n = *n3;
    *n3 = *n4;
    *n4 = n;
}
```

And the output is:

```
This program, or function, substitutes one given number for another given number, and then places the former with the latter number. 

The numbers' given values before the aforementioned function:  Number 1 = 10.000000 , Number 2 = 20.000000  , Number 3 = &f , Number 4 =
30.000000

The numbers' given values after the aforementioned function:   Number 1 = 20.000000 , Number 2 = 10.000000  , Number 3 = &f , Number 4 =
40.000000
```

My question is: how do I change the code so that "number 3" substitutes itself just like the rest of the variables.

Comment: Tip: Enable highlighting and compiler warnings.

Comment: Your `sub()` function, which swaps numbers around, accepts `float` values. But your temporary variables `z` and `n` are declared `int`.

Comment: @steveha: I wouldn't take every suggestion of some one with a fraction of your rep so seriously. I saw nothing wrong with your answer, particularly as it added more insight than typical comments..

Answer (score 3):

You simply have a typo: change &f to %f for

Number 3 = &f

Answer (score 0):

The trouble is with your printf. Please change `&f` to `%f` in your printf statement for number 3.